# Submitting errors to frontend with joi

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, joi

I have a registration form and I am validating this form with joi.
There is no problem so far, I can reflect the errors as json, but I don't know how to print it in the frontend, how can I do that?

I used express-validator before, there was a validationresult structure there, so I could catch errors and send them to the front end. How can I do this here?
can you help me.

Validate process like this

```
const createUserValidation = Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required().min(5),
    username : Joi.string().required().min(3),
    password : Joi.string().required().min(8).pattern(new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$')),
    email: Joi.string().required().email(),

});
```

In short, I want to transfer the errors returned from here to the front end.

Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have to create a Try and catch, and send a JSON error:

```
catch (error) {            
  res.status(400).json({
    success: false,
    message: 'This is ur message'
  })
}
```

Now, you can change the "message" for your new error:

```
catch (error) {            
  res.status(400).json({
    success: false,
    message: error.message
  })
}
```

With that, you can send the message to the front, and there just have to read it... For that, if u use Redux, can

```
let [functionRedux, {data : yourRedux , error}] = useFunctionMutation()
let msg = ""


if (yourRedux ?.success) {
  msg = yourRedux ?.message
} else {
  msg = error?.data.message
}
```

And with that, you can get the error to your front =)

R³